# How to get path in matlab relative to specified path that is stored in variable

Tags: matlab

I have a path of currently executing script stored as:

```
currentDir = mfilename('fullpath');
```

I need to get path , 2 levels up from this path.
I know that

```
'..\..\'
```

would do the job if executed within the script. But, i need a solution that  can do similar stuff using the variable *currentDir*.

Thanks
sedy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`find`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to locate the *third* occurence of `\` (or [`filesep`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filesep.html) for more generality) starting *from the end* of the string, and cut there:

```
currentDir = 'C:\example\path\to\file\filename.m'; %// example full filename
ind = find(currentDir==filesep,3,'last');
result = currentDir(1:ind(1)-1);
```

In this example,

```
result =
    C:\example\path
```

Comment: Thanks Luis ,that works for me. however, I still wanted to know if there was a way to combine '..\..\' with given variable to construct the required path.

Comment: What do you mean by "combine '..\..\' with given variable"? Perhaps `cd(changeDir), cd('..\..\')`?